# Galaxy S3 zoom when switch from landscape to portrait

Tags: android, responsive-design, android-browser

I'm working on a responsive design, and I hit a little issue on galaxy S3 which behave weird when I switch from landscape to portrait. The zoom used in landscape view is still here when I switch back to portrait, unlike other android phone (tested on xperia Z and HTC one X too)

I'm using the following viewport :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=321, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1, target-densitydpi=device-dpi">
```

The problem only occurs on default browser, chrome is doing good.

Comment: Why do you set a width?

Comment: some elements of the html/css are quick made, i plan to adapt it to work with width=device-width, but ATM the website isn't well displayed with width=device-width